# DynamoDB PutItem not awaiting, or executing finally blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My Lambda takes in an SQS message containing an ID and address. It parses out those fields, and updates the record associated with that ID in a dynamo table.

The parameters for this update contain the following logic

1.Where the record has a id  equal to the ID sent by SQS

2.And where the SortKey has a value equal to “null” (Note that null is specifically a String with a value of “null”)

3.Update the address field with the new address

I'm seeing the following issues with this function

1. The function is not updating the DynamoDB instance
2. I am not receiving any kind of feedback from the update call. Looking over the code there are several console.logs that should execute but are not. See the Try,Catch,Finally block after the update. Looking at the logs you can see that these do not output to the console. Something is very wrong here. The finally not executing looks like undefined behavior, my only guess is that the call to dynamodb is not being awaited

I also need to implement the following functionality. This is bonus points, if you have an idea of how to do it please feel free to comment!

Right now the update will only change the fieldname of address from one value to another. Instead, I need the record to contain a set of addresses associated with that record. To do this we need to implement the following logic

If a set of addresses does not exist on the record, create a set with the address as the only element
If a set does exist on the student record, update that set with the address. Duplicate addresses should not be added

The code for this function is below. I’ve also attached the most recent CloudWatch log for this function, and the record I am trying to update (the address field on the record was added manually).  You’ll notice that we aren’t getting any console.logs after console.log("starting upload"), and the promise has a state “PENDING” when it is examined. We also don’t get any feedback from the dynamodb update. Right now the function is not updating the record, and not giving me any feedback for why it is failing to do so.

```
const util = require('util')
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();



exports.handler = async(event) => {

    event.Records.forEach(async record => {
        const { body } = record;
        const test = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(test);
        const message = JSON.parse(test["Message"]);
        console.log(message);

        const id = message.id;
        const name = message.Name;
        const address = message.address;
        console.log("parameters parsed");
        console.log("record being processed is " + id);

        const params = {
            TableName: "My_Records",
            Key: {
                "ID": ":id",
                "SortKey": ":sortKey"
            },
            //KeyConditionExpression: 'SortKey = :sortKey',
            UpdateExpression: "set info.address = :address",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':id': id,
                ':address': address,
                ':sortKey': "null"
            },
            ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
        };
        console.log(params)

        console.log("starting upload")
        try {
            let putObjectPromise = docClient.update(params).promise();
            console.log(util.inspect(putObjectPromise, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
            putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:");
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Unable to update item. Error JSON:" + err);
            }).finally(() =>
                console.log("done with upload")
            );
            return putObjectPromise
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.err(err)
        }

    });
};
```

CloudWatch log of the most recent execution of this function

```
INFO {
Type: 'Notification',
MessageId: 'ID',
TopicArn: 'ARN',
Subject: 'DB updated',
SignatureVersion: '1',
INFO { id: '11111111', Name: 'Jerms Macgee', address: '102 homeslice lane' }
INFO parameters parsed
INFO record being processed is 11111111
INFO {
TableName: 'my_table',
Key: { ID: ':id', SortKey: ':sortKey' },
UpdateExpression: 'set info.address = :address',
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
':id': '11111111',
':address': '102 homeslice lane',
':sortKey': 'null'
},
ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
}
INFO starting upload
INFO Promise { <pending> }
END RequestId
```

And here's an example of the record I'd expect to be updated

```
{
  "address": "test",
  "SortKey": "null",
  "id": 11111111
  "name": James Mcgee
}
```

The updated record should be

```
{
  "address": "102 homeslice lane",
  "SortKey": "null",
  "id": 11111111
  "name": James Mcgee
}
```

And for bonus points I'd really like to do something like

```
{
  "address": {"102 homeslice lane"},
  "SortKey": "null",
  "id": 11111111
  "name": James Mcgee
}
```

where addresses is a set that can hold other records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your async/promise stuff.

First, event.Records.forEach isn't going to wait for the async function you're passing to it to resolve, you can change it to:

```
await Promise.all(event.Records.map(async record => {
  ///... the rest of your function body
});
```

This way your main handler function will actually wait for them all to resolve.

Next, all this stuff:

```
try {
        let putObjectPromise = docClient.update(params).promise();
        console.log(util.inspect(putObjectPromise, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
        putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:");
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Unable to update item. Error JSON:" + err);
        }).finally(() =>
            console.log("done with upload")
        );
        return putObjectPromise
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.err(err)
    }
```

is weird, you're using `.then` and callback functions, but you're in an async function so you can just await them. Eg:

```
try {
        const putObjectResponse = await docClient.update(params).promise();
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(putObjectResponse));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Unable to update item. Error JSON:" + err);
        console.err(err)
    }
 console.log("done with upload")
```

By awaiting `update(params).promise()` the return value becomes what the promise resolves to, not the promise. If the promise rejects, it is thrown and caught in your catch block.

This also fixes your weird logging messages because you're now logging the resolved value from the promise rather than the promise itself.

Answer (score 2):

First, `forEach` won't work with async/await callback. The example from https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

```js
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
[1, 2, 3].forEach(async (num) => {
  await waitFor(50);
  console.log(num);
});
console.log('Done');
```

Second, if you wrap a rejected promise in a `try/catch` block and that promise already has a `.catch()` set, catch block will never be executed.

```js
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        reject(123);
    }, ms)
});
try {
    waitFor(2000).catch(e => { console.log(e) })
} catch (error) {
    console.error('error');
}
```

Comment: Hey trmaphi, thanks for the feedback. Check out my updated code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564242/dynamodb-update-does-not-console-log-any-output